# How to allow only one person at a time to use discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, queue

So I have this line of code:

```
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == "!test":
    await asyncio.sleep(15)
    await message.channel.send("Hello world"!)
```

If I want this line of code to run ONLY to one person at a time (that is, if someone else is using the bot other people will not be able to use the bot), how should I code this?

I'm using `discord.Client()` instead of `discord.Bot()`, and I intend to keep it that way.

Comment: discord.Client wasn't really made for making commands, since you are using !test I assume it's a command so you should really use commands.Bot, if you did use commands.Bot, the feature could be added in just one line using commands.max_concurrency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make that only 1 person can use it at a time so you can add an if statement as I have added below:

```py
occupied = False
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global occupied
    if not occupied:
        occupied = True
    elif occupied:
        await ctx.send("Someone is using command pls wait")
        return
    if message.content == "!test":
        await asyncio.sleep(15)
        await message.channel.send("Hello world"!)
```

I have added the if statement so if someone runs command var occupied will be true and then if someone else tries to run the command it will show someone is using it.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tweaked this code to adjust it to my full code and it worked :)

Comment: No problem :) 

Comment: @DjWalkzz, you can use else instead of elif occupied, right?

Comment: yea , i just added elif to confirm that occupied is true