# How to make application bot available for more than one user at a time?

Tags: discord.py

when the application bot is used by more than 1 person at a time it merges the answers from applicant A and applicant B and sends them as 1 application.

I thought about limiting the bot's usage to 1 person at a time but didn't know how to do it.

here's the code:

````py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!add'):
        var = list2.append #This list will have the raw answers
        var3 = list3.append #THis list will have the questions and the answers lined up like this format {Question}: {Answer} 
        await message.author.send(
                    "``Fill in the blanks by replying, then the bot will give a confirmation message.``")

        for element in report:      
            await message.author.send("**"+element+"**") #Sends the questions 
            try:
                response = await client.wait_for('message',check=check,timeout=60*20) #waits for response for only 20 minutes
                var(response.content) # if the response is sent before the 20min window closes it will add the response in list2
            except asyncio.TimeoutError: #if there was no answer during the 20min window this script will run to abort 
                await message.author.send("```Report timed out, it will be deleted. ❌```")
                list2.clear() #clears previous answered questions
                return #prevents the rest of the code from running


        if len(list2) == 10: #There are in list Report 10 questions. so when the answers reach 10 this will run
            for i in range(len(list2)): #this will add the questions and the answers lined up in a single list 
                var3(report[i] + list2[i])


            for element in list3:
                await message.author.send(element + "\n") #this will send the questions and answers in dm for the user to double check

            await message.author.send( content="**Double check the report then submit.:arrow_up:** \n```You got only 1min to submit!```", components=[Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Submit")]) #sends confirmation button

            try:
                i=await client.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("Submit"),timeout=60) #if the "Submit" button is clicked on time
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await message.author.send("```Submission timed out, report will get deleted. ❌```")
                list2.clear()
                list3.clear()
                return
            await i.respond(content="**" + "Report added Successfully" + "**" + ":white_check_mark:") #this will be sent in dm for confiramation

            for element in list3:
                await message.channel.send(element + "\n") #this will send the Questions and the Answers in a channel that the !add command was initiated in.
````

Comment: pls check https://stackoverflow.com/a/69099468/14663777

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow only one person at a time to use discord bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69097269/how-to-allow-only-one-person-at-a-time-to-use-discord-bot)

Comment: I will consider this as a second option if i couldn't make the bot available for more than 1 user at a time. Thank you anyway 

Comment: I tried the same thing in my bot and it didn't worked at all then I used the same logic

Comment: @FerisDaou It might be preferable to [edit existing question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303634/what-is-the-accepted-method-of-renewing-interest-in-a-question).

Comment: @SuvenPandey my last question wasn't clear so starting all over again was easier than editing.